# Convert Json schema to Graphql schema in Java Spring

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am a newbie to graphql. In our spring boot application, we are saving JSON schema in the database. The application should generate a possible graphql schema from the JSON schema and the generated schema needs to be federated.
Can someone help me with this? Are there any maven plugins that can provide this functionality ?

Comment: hi there ... have you succeeded with such idea?